# Python - print 'object' information

Tags: python

I have a variable that is outputing this when I do a simple for loop:

```
for filex in variable:

    print filex

# OUTPUT #

'proj1' (objectName 0x2267c4f0)
'proj2' (objectName 0x2267a770)
'proj3' (objectName 0x22679690)
'proj4' (objectName 0x2267d0d0)

# OUTPUT #
```

I Want to extract just the text between quotes like 'proj1'. But I get this error when using indexing:

```
for filex in variable:

    print filex[0]

# OUTPUT #

  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: 'objectName' object does not support indexing

# OUTPUT #
```

*I am using python inside an host application.

Comment: Seems like `filex` is an object of a custom class that does not implement `__getitem__` method.

Comment: what about `print fstr(ilex[0])`?

Comment: `filex` is an element of `variable`. In general, it may or may not be an iterable... (as `variable` obviously is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you find out the name of that attribute you want,
e.g. if it was `name`, then you can access it directly with `filex.name` where `'proj1'` is stored

If you don't know what that attribute is, you can use `dir(filex)` to see all the attributes

Comment: When I do that for the attribute "name" I get this:

<qt slot setName of name instance at 0x0000000017834258>

Comment: I don't know what the actual name of the attribute is, `filex.name` is an example, you have to find the real attribute name by reading the source or using `dir(filex)` and see if something matches what you want to display

Comment: all attributes output that result, I already did the dir(filex) to check the attributes:

I get this: ['BASIC', 'BitDepth', 'DEPTH_BYTE', 'DEPTH_FLOAT', 'DEPTH_HALF',...etc

Comment: Is this some Qt object? Either way if we know what object it is, we can read the documentation and get the attribute you want to print, without any hacks like `repr(filex)`

Comment: I was missing the brackets, stupid me: .name() thank you

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `filex` is an object of a custom class that does not implement `__getitem__` method.

When you do:

```
filex[0]
```

What actually is invoked is:

```
filex.__getitem__(0)
```

The output string `"'proj1' (objectName 0x2267c4f0)"` is likely the returned value from `filex.__str__` or `filex.__repr__`.

If so, the `'proj1'` string you're looking for might be accessible from one of `filex`'s other attributes or methods associated with them.

Barring that, you can hack your way by parsing the returned value of `repr(filex)`, but that's not really robust, IMO.